# C++ using strcpy_s() on a Pointer to char array Pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am to the point I am confusing myself but here is what I have. I have only recently started to familiarize myself with pointers more to a point I feel more comfortable using them, but I am getting an error about the buffer in strcpy_s() being too small.

Please no comments about me using char arrays instead of std::string, its for the HL2SDK which centers around char arrays (no idea why) so I just stick to the pattern.

```
void func_a()
{
    char *szUserID = new char[64];
    char *szInviterID = new char[64];
    char *szGroupID = new char[64];
    sprintf(szUserID, "%I64d", GetCommunityID(szUserSteamID));
    sprintf(szInviterID, "%I64d", GetCommunityID(g_CvarSteamID.GetString()));
    GetGroupCommunityID(1254745, &szGroupID); // Group Steam Community ID
}

void GetGroupCommunityID(int groupID, char **communityID)
{
    int staticID = 1035827914;
    int newGroupID = 29521408 + groupID;

    char *buffer = new char[64];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d%d", staticID, newGroupID);
    strcpy_s(*communityID, sizeof(*communityID), buffer);

    delete buffer;
}
```

Comment: If you need a dynamically allocated array of `char`, you can usually get away with using a `std::vector<char>`.  I don't see why that wouldn't work here.

Comment: Why are you newing and deleting char buffers that can be done perfectly well just declared on the stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are using `sizeof` which is a compile time construct to determine the runtime length of `*communityID`.  This will essentially resolve down to `sizeof(char*)`.  What you want though is the number of bytes / chars available in `*communityID`.  This information needs to be passed along with the value

```
GetGroupCommunityID(1254745, &szGroupID, sizeof(szGroupID));

void GetGroupCommunityID(int groupId, char** communityID, size_t length) {
  ...
  strcpy_s(*communityID, length, buffer);
}
```

Also in this example a double pointer is unnecessary because you're not changing the pointer, just it's contents.  A single pointer will do just fine for that

```
GetGroupCommunityID(1254745, szGroupID, sizeof(szGroupID));

void GetGroupCommunityID(int groupId, char* communityID, size_t length) {
  ...
  strcpy_s(communityID, length, buffer);
}
```

Comment: "a compile time construct to determine the runtime length" -- is that not an oxymoron?

Comment: @Alex it is and hence why the original solution failed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using constants values (char *szGroupID = new char[64]) why not declare a constant with the value 64 and use this value; by the way sizeof(szGroupID) is going to return 4 bytes too in a 32 bits compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `strcpy_s` is the actual size (number of characters) of the buffer pointed to by the first parameter. `sizeof(*communityID)` only gives you the size of a `char *` pointer, typically 4 bytes on a 32-bit system. You need to pass in the actual size of `*communityID` to the `GetGroupCommunityID` function and pass this on to `strcpy_s`.